# ERROR: Right To Be Forgotten is enabled. MarketingCloudSDK functionality has been restricted

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios, mobilepush, mobilepush-ios

When configuring the marketing cloud SDK on iOS, I receive this error on initialization:

> Right To Be Forgotten is enabled. MarketingCloudSDK functionality has been restricted.

What are the consequences of this error on my code? I've read that it affects contact key registration. Is it true? what is the limitation, and should I be worried about it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

RTBF (GDPR) functionality is Contact Key based.  If you've "deleted" your contact in the Marketing Cloud you will need to contact your Salesforce Account Manager and/or Support Contact.

This is *not* an SDK error, but rather an information message telling you that the SDK has been instructed by the servers to cease communication with the servers.

If you are able to get the deletion removed from your contact then clearing the application data on your device will result in the application reaching out to the servers again.  Note, however, that it will simply re-restrict communication if you've failed to have your contact restored first.